# Why isn't there any "original" Japanese word for "page"?

Tags: etymology

In my last Japanese class, I asked my teacher, who is a native speaker, why the Japanese word for "page" was taken from the English language ("pēji"), because apparently there were already books ("hon"), who had a Japanese name. My teacher could not answer me this. Is there a reason and, more important, how did the Japanese people called a sheet of paper being part of a book?

Comment: This link would help you. https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1112532261

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/16245/5010

Answer (score 4):

頁 `おおがい`(ケツ or ヨウ) is used to indicate the pages in Kanji, which is quite rare to see nowadays.

Originally, 「葉」-leaf (ヨウ) was said to be the unit of count for paper and in Edo period we borrowed the kanji 頁 so to mean the pages because its Chinese pronunciation is similar to ‘ヨウ’.

http://kanjibunka.com/kanji-faq/old-faq/q0153/