# adverbial form of an adjective to modify a noun?

Tags: adverbs, i-adjectives

I am learning from Japanese From Zero! online website, and came across this sentence:

きょう、近くの こうえんに 行きませんか

I would expected 近く to read 近い

I have never seen the adverbial form of an adjective used to modify a noun before?

Comment: 近く is quite an unusual word. See this link and the links referenced within: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/54414/%e8%bf%91%e3%81%8f%e3%81%ae%e6%98%a0%e7%94%bb%e9%a4%a8-vs-%e8%bf%91%e3%81%84%e6%98%a0%e7%94%bb%e9%a4%a8

Comment: Also related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/27286/5010