# What is the difference between ちゃいろ and ちゃいろい

Tags: word-choice, words

I saw both used for brown but looking at Google Translate it doesn't help me to understand what the difference is between the two. Can someone help me.

Comment: ちゃいろい has an extra 「い」 on the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

茶色    　　/  茶色い, 茶色の

ちゃいろ　/　 ちゃいろい

Noun　　 / 　　Adj.

> https://hinative.com/en-US/questions/380841
>
> 「赤い(red)」　　　「青い(blue)」　　　「白い(white)」　　　「黒い(black)」
>
> 「黄色い(yellow)」　　　「茶色い(blown)」　　　-- adjectives.

The tricky part is ...

Sometimes, you can't add　　  い 　　 at the end.

> noun:　　　noun+の　　 ("no" adjective)
>
> みどり：　　 みどりの 　　 green
>
> むらさき：　　 むらさきの　　  purple
>
> ピンク：　　 ピンクの 　　 pink

Anything else that 's tricky or interesting ?

Brownish　 　　茶色っぽい

There's an elaborate 5- year old page here:
[Historical differences between colors that are i-adjectives and those that are simply nouns](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2288/historical-differences-between-colors-that-are-i-adjectives-and-those-that-are-s)

Comment: The formatting in your answers is very hard to read.  Maybe you could avoid putting strange spacing into your comments and answers?

Comment: 全角ブランクだ！that's the way Japanese is formatted on a computer. In a way, it could be considered part of the Japanese language. All of us on this side of the pond had to get used to it ;)

Comment: @Mark そういう問題ではないと思いますが・・・

Comment: @Mark No, we would say 全角スペース.

Comment: It's an IT term I guess. Those things cause us so much trouble (I work in Japan with all Japanese)

Comment: I have to admit that I also never have read an answer of yours because of difficult-to-read formatting. Using 全角スペース as a hack for alignment tabs etc. might work if we had a font where the full-width space is displayed as such across all devices and browsers. Unfortunately such a font doesn't exist.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/EhE1j.png