# Use of の in colored objects

Tags: grammar, nuances, particles

It seems to me that some colors need の when describing an item, yet others don't.

For example:

- 黄色のくつ (Yellow shoes; has の)
- 赤いくつ (Red shoes; no の)
- オレンジ色のくつ (Orange shoes; has の)
- 青いくつ (Blue shoes; no の)

It would seem the kanji for color (色) isn't always mandatory, which I would guess is also related.

Is there some kind of distinction per color, or is it just two ways of saying the same thing?

Comment: Related: [Historical differences between colors that are i-adjectives and those that are simply nouns](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2288/historical-differences-between-colors-that-are-i-adjectives-and-those-that-are-s)