# Aoi aoi morideshita - sentence structure explanation

Tags: grammar, syntax

first post here. I'm currently reading a children's books titled 'きつね森の山男'. I think it's a good starters book however, some of the structures are confusing  or contrary to what I have learnt. 
I understand the phrase ' aoi aoi morideshita' to mean 'the forest was blue'. I'm sure there is some rule I haven't seen yet, or some obviation to a rule, but wouldn't 'mori ha aokatta desu' mean the same thing?

Thanks guys! (P.S I'm sure I'll be posting more questions about this book!)

Comment: Hello Kaney, just a tip here, in english we can also say things like "The car was black" and "it was a black car" to mean roughly the same thing, right? The focus changes a little bit though, but what I mean is that there are usually more than one way to say things.

Comment: Ah I see, similar to Portuguese/Spanish where you can omit the subject/pronoun from the sentence. Of course it had to be something simple haha, thanks for your fast reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're comfortable with hiragana, since you're reading this book!

> あおい あおい もり でした。

Means "it was a green, green forest." (In Japanese, あおい is often used for things we'd called "green" in English, such as trees and traffic lights.)

As Felipe Oliveira explained, in Japanese as in English, an adjective can come before or after its noun, depending on what you want to emphasis and how you want the phrase to sound.

> おおきいいぬでした。

It was a big dog.

> いぬはおおきかったです。

The dog was big.

Comment: Ah I see now, even though the topic marker isn't used it still translates to English with the subject as 'it'. Thanks for your fast reply!

Comment: `In Japanese, あおい is often used for things we'd called "green" in English` ← But they do say "bluegrass", "Blue Mountains", etc. in English as well.

Comment: But *bluegrass* is from the color it flowers (when it's allowed to bloom); *blue mountains* from the surrounding blue haze; *blue ash* from the tint the bark gives water; and so on.  The English *blue* for things that are not obviously blue in each case has a different story behind it.

Comment: See https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/1056/88.